How to authenticate and get credentials with Google OAuth 2.0 running in Cloud Run?
First of all, I'm very new to APIs and server settings.
I'm trying to get Google APIs credentials using the function I've made to gain access to use the Google Tasks API in my Python script (not shown here). I'm running the script on Google Cloud Run.
def authenticate():
creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('/work/credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

return creds

When I run this file, I always get the error from my error handler
Error occurred: could not locate runnable browser

I did some searching online and it says it's because Google Cloud Run does not support GUIs or browsers. If so, how do I get my Google APIs credentials when running in Cloud Run?

What is your goal? The Quickstart provides code that assumes it will be running locally so that the user can authenticate using their user credentials (e.g. somebody@gmail.com) using 3-legged OAuth. However. when you run code on e.g. Cloud Run, the code runs as a Service Account identity.

If you're using Google Workspace accounts, such a Service Account must either be configured as a Domain-wide Delegate (DwD) or it must impersonate a DwD and, while impersonating the DwD, it must impersonate the Google Workspace user account that owns the Google Tasks API resources. Unfortunately, Google's Python libraries don't make this process straightforward.

Alternatively, if you're not using Google Workspace (i.e. you're using a Gmail account), then you can't use DwD but you may be able to use a hack that involves creating a Service Account, sharing the Google resource with it and then using the Service Account instead of the Gmail account to access the resource in your code. Unfortunately, I think that you cannot share Google Tasks (as you can with e.g. Drive files) and so I think this approach is not possible.

The OAuth Flow you coded is designed to run on a client desktop with a web browser. That is the wrong design for a server (backend). There are many Google OAuth examples on the Internet plus Google provides auth examples in Python. Review the documentation before posting a problem so that you know what method to implement first. Throw away the code you wrote and start over. Tips: Cloud Run already provides authorization. You are trying to add authorization on top of authorization. Practice with OAuth on your local computer before deployment to Cloud Run.
